# How to stub a required function in Sinon?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, chai, sinon

I am trying to stub a required function in my file. For example:

**fileA.js**

```
function doSomething() {
  return 5;
}

modules.export = { doSomething }
```

**fileB.js**

```
const { doSomething } = require('./fileA');

function doAnotherThing() {
  let anotherThing = 10;
  return anotherThing + doSomething();
}

modules.export = { doAnotherThing }
```

And in my test file: **fileBTest.js**

```
const fileA = require('./fileA');
const fileB = require('./fileB');

describe('Test File B', function(){
  it('Example of failing stub', function() {
    const fileAStub = sinon.stub(fileA, 'doSomething');
    fileAStub.returns(15);

    expect(fileB.doAnotherThing()).to.equal(25);
  })
})
```

However, my `fileAStub` is not working because in fileB.js, it is required as a function and not the entire fileA being required.

If I change the way I require fileA in fileB.js to the following, my stub will work.

**updatedFileB.js**

```
const fileA = require('./fileA');

function doAnotherThing() {
  let anotherThing = 10;
  return anotherThing + fileA.doSomething();
}
```

Question: How can I stub `{ doSomething }` instead of changing the way I do require in fileB?

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to make it work, but the file that I was testing was requiring, the module that I wanted to test, like this `const { get: myFuncName } = require('./some-module')` therefore `sinon.stub` wasn't working. Changing it to `const someModule = require('./some-module')` and now calling it `someModule.get` is stubbed perfectly.